# Addition to Subtraction logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Here is my Code
I cant figure out how to change the logic to subtraction

```
   var slices = $("#slices");
var options = $("#options");
var area = $("#area");

var selected;
var result;

//---Array of images
var pizzas = [
    {image: "http://s23.postimg.org/6yojml8vb/Pizza_One.png", value: 1},
  {image: "http://s13.postimg.org/5d8zxnb2b/pizzatwo.png", value: 2},
  {image: "http://s12.postimg.org/xfsxldqyx/pizzathree.png", value: 3},
  {image: "http://s14.postimg.org/d6tdq0865/pizzafour.png", value: 4}
];
var total = pizzas.length;

//---Make boxes dragables
options.find("div").draggable();

//---When the boxes are dropped
area.droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui){

    if( Number( ui.draggable.attr("data-index") ) == result ){

        alert("correct");

    }else{

        alert("incorrect");

    }

  }

});

//---Insert random pizza slices
function insertPizzas(){

    selected = [];
  result = 0;

  //---Generate aleatory pieces
  var rand

  while(selected.length < 2){

        //---Random value
    rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * total );

    //---Sum result
    result += pizzas[rand].value;

    selected.push( rand );

  }

    //---Clear the slices
    slices.html("");

  //---Add the new slices
  selected.forEach(function(number){

    var img = $("<img/>");

    img.attr("src", pizzas[number].image);

    slices.append(img);

  });

}

insertPizzas();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/2u5xtkv2/

How would i change the logic to go from addition to subtraction?

I also have this code on one part of my html page and Im working on new variable names

Comment: Do you mean to show two images, where the user would take image 1 minus image 2 and drag the number into the drop area as the answer?

Comment: yes sir ! that is what i want

Comment: i linked the fiddle and my addition code is working exactly like that i just want to get the subtraction part working whichyou will ahve to subtract the pizzas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the jsfiddle update to handle subtraction:

https://jsfiddle.net/wvary/2u5xtkv2/8/

Function taken from the new fiddle:

```
//---Insert random pizza slices
function insertPizzas() {

    selected = [];
    result = 0;

    //---Generate aleatory pieces
    var rand = 0;

    while (selected.length < 2) {

        //---Making sure first number is greater than 0 (0 is the index so it is actually has a value of 1)
        while (selected.length === 0 && rand === 0) {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
            console.log('first: ' + rand);
        }

        //---Making sure second number is greater than first number
        while (selected.length === 1 && rand >= result) {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
            console.log('second: ' + rand);
        }

        //---Because of the number values, we can simply use the index difference as the values
        //---Of course, we have to update our code if the values are different
        if (selected.length === 0) {
            result = rand;
        } else {
            result -= rand;
        }

        selected.push(rand);

    }

    //---Clear the slices
    slices.html("");

    //---Add the new slices
    selected.forEach(function(number) {

        var img = $("<img/>");

        img.attr("src", pizzas[number].image);

        slices.append(img);

    });

}
```

A few things to take notice:

1. We must loop in the first iteration to make sure the first index is not 0 because first number minus second number must be greater than 0 since our choices are 1 through 8.
2. We must loop in the second iteration to make sure the second number is less than the first number for the same reason as #1.
3. Since our values are all difference of 1, we can simply use index as our difference.
4. Also we must initialize the rand value to 0 for the first loop to work.

Comment: this works great will! thank you, quick question i just plugged this into my code and it seems like the scripts are interfering with each other (addition + subtraction) what variable names do i change to get the scripts working independently?

Comment: @artbarzz - Update your fiddle so we can review and suggest.

Comment: i want to use both the addition script and the subtraction script in one html file and i want to use the same html calls to the javascript code

Comment: @artbarzz - Do you mean to have one single function to generate the images.  The call can be either for addition or subtraction?

Comment: yes sir i am using one of the pages called addition to make an addition game and another page to make subtraction game and both will use this code but i need to change it for each page so the logic works

Comment: @artbarzz - I updated this fiddle to produce addition and subtraction: https://jsfiddle.net/wvary/2u5xtkv2/9/
Notice you can call it with '+' or '-'.

Comment: one second i will try it

Comment: in the html how does it know if its subtraction or addition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98518/discussion-between-artbarzz-and-will).

Comment: @artbarzz - See where I put insertPizzas('-'); in the javascript?  Remove it from your js file.  Add this to the end of the html file:
<script>
  insertPizzas('-');
</script>
Because jsfiddle is different, so you can't test this approach in it, but it should work in your html page.